# Concating a String from an arraylist

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I have an array list `ArrayList<String> firstname;` In this I am storing n number of names which have been parsed from an xml file.

Now from this ArrayList I need to take all the names and store it in a Single separate
`String names` along with a `slash(/)` between of each names.

```
For eg firstname= {a, c,f,g,h,j,k}
```

Now i want it to be as follows names= a/c/f/g/h/j/k

So far I have created a for loop to get values from the ArrayList by its size

```
String names;
 for(int k=0;k<Appconstant.firstname.size();k++) {
    names = Appconstant.firstname.get(k);
 }
```

Comment: Side note: why doesn't java have a built-in String.join()? >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String names = TextUtils.join("/", Appconstant.firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String names;
 for(int k=0;k<Appconstant.firstname.size();k++)
       {
        if(k<=Appconstant.firstname.size()-1)
            names += Appconstant.firstname.get(k)+"/";
        else
           names += Appconstant.firstname.get(k)
      }
```

Though you should be using a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: are you kidding me?! you want me to add a Jar just for line of code?!  it's not like I'm designing a rocket  here! What if this is a company project and request, that too an idiotic one, for adding a new jar just for a couple of lines of code gets rejected?

Comment: Textutils is part of android.text and provides clean and reusable solution in one short line of code, it does not require any additional jars (it's part of android.jar since API level 1), just a package import which eclipse assists with. Only a masochist would rewrite your solution every time it is needed as it must be read to understand the behaviour. It could easily could introduce a bug, thereby wasting time and money so your argument is flawed. As a company director I would sack anybody who coded 8 lines where 1 would suffice. Code should be easily readable, maintainable and error free.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, but something like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String name : firstname)
{
    builder.append(name).append('/');
}
// Remove last '/'
builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length()-1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
StringBuilder myStrBuilder = null;

for(String aName:yourNameList)
{
  myStrBUilder.append(aName+"/");
}

myStrBuilder.deleteCharAt(myStrBUilder.length()-1)
```

Comment: ROFL.. it's like a rat race in here.. Don't get a lot of questions like these.. :D

Comment: don't forget to catch that NPE